# How to read Bluetooth RSSI value in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-phone

I am searching for Windows Phone 8 API that allows me to read Bluetooth RSSI value. However, I couldn't find any resource that is useful for me.

Does the Windows Phone 8 API support reading Bluetooth RSSI value?

Looking forward for your help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

[32feet](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) has a wrapper [BluetoothDeviceInfo.Rssi](http://inthehand.com/library/html/T_InTheHand_Net_Sockets_BluetoothDeviceInfo.htm). They say that it requires

> Requires .NET Compact Framework v3.5 or above and Windows CE.NET 4.2
>   or above, or .NET Framework v3.5 for desktop Windows XP, Vista, 7 and
>   8. A subset of functionality is available for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Embedded Handheld 8 in the InTheHand.Phone.Bluetooth.dll
>   library.

Comment: It seems that 32feet for Windows Phone does not support reading RSSI value.